# Get first array of numbers in array of variable depth

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am using a function in a JavaScript framework where the return value can be **ANY** of the following

1. a single xy coordinate pair

   ```
   [x,y]
   ```
2. an array of xy coordinate pairs

   ```
   [[x,y],[x,y],...]
   ```
3. an array of arrays of xy coordinate pairs

   ```
   [[[x,y],[x,y]],[[x,y],[x,y]],...]
   ```

The return value depends on the geometry of the object (single point, line, or multiple lines).  Regardless of the return value and its array depth, I want to grab the first xy coordinate pair.  What is an efficient way to do this?

Here is my code to achieve the objective so far:

```
//here is the magic method that can return one of three things :)
var mysteryCoordinates = geometry.getCoordinates();
var firstCoord;

if(typeof mysteryCoordinates[0] === 'number') {
    firstCoord = mysteryCoordinates;
} else if (typeof mysteryCoordinates[0][0] === 'number') {
    firstCoord = mysteryCoordinates[0];
} else if (typeof mysteryCoordinates[0][0][0] === 'number') {
    firstCoord = mysteryCoordinates[0][0];
}
```

I really hate this solution and am looking for something a bit more elegant.

Comment: Does the `geometry` object not have some property telling you what type of geometry it represents, ie point,line,lines?

Comment: __I want to grab the first xy coordinate pair__ are you interested only on the first pair ?? Or later you might want some other index data as well?

Comment: @PatrickEvans It does, but I would have to do three separate typeof checks on the geometry object to know the proper depth to access the first coordinate pair.

Comment: @Reddy Yes, I am only interested in the first pair.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess in pure JS this should do it;

```js
var    arr = [[[1,2],[1,3]],[[4,8],[3,9]]],
getFirstXY = a => Array.isArray(a[0]) ? getFirstXY(a[0]) : a;

console.log(getFirstXY(arr));
```

Comment: you need no concat.

Comment: @Nina Scholz  Cool..! Thanks :)

Comment: @Redu This works for all 3 scenarios.  Care to explain what is going on?

Comment: @JellyRaptor `getFirstXY` is a recursive function. It checks for the first item of the supplied array and if it is an array calls `getFirstXY` again with a[0] being the argument up until it is not and then returns the argument array.

Comment: @Redu This is pretty awesome.  Answer accepted.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A less efficient, but more elegant solution would be to use `_.flatten` (http://underscorejs.org/#flatten):

```
let firstCoord = _.flatten(mysteryCoordinates).slice(0, 2);
```

You could make it a little more efficient on average by slicing off the first two elements up-front as well:

```
let firstCoord = _.flatten(mysteryCoordinates.slice(0, 2)).slice(0, 2);
```

```js
console.log(_.flatten([1,2]).slice(0, 2));
console.log(_.flatten([[1,2],[1,3],[4,8],[3,9]]).slice(0, 2));
console.log(_.flatten([[[1,2],[1,3]],[[4,8],[3,9]]]).slice(0, 2));
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Upon further review, this solution only works for scenarios 1 and 2, but not 3.  It spits out an array of pairs when the input is the array of arrays of pairs.

Comment: Seems to work for me with the latest version of underscore. Maybe you accidentally passed a truthy value for `shallow`?

Comment: +1 for demonstrating functionality.  I initially checked results using the flatten() function from the latest lodash version.  I presumed it would be equivalent to underscore's flatten, but evidently it is not.